# Extract simple text from HTML on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html-parsing

```
 <div dir="ltr"> TEXT TO EXTRACT </div>

<div dir="ltr"> TEXT &amp; MORE TEXT&quot;TEXT&quot; TEXT</div>
```

Above are examples of the HTML I wish to extract the text into an NSString, ignoring the div wrapper and any other 'stuff' - Some have `<BR>` included and some have ISO codes (can't remember exact name for these e.g &amp)

many thanks

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this catagory:

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

works great.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a stronger solution would be to parse the HTML using a Library.

A link and example in this question.

[Simple libxml2 HTML parsing example, using Objective-c, Xcode, and HTMLparser.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h)