# Objective C HTML parser error "expected expression before xmlNode"

Tags: objective-c, ios, html-parsing

Was following this [Simple libxml2 HTML parsing example, using Objective-c, Xcode, and HTMLparser.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h) and http://benreeves.co.uk/objective-c-hmtl-parser/

The author notes that there's something wrong with rawContentsOfNode method.

```
NSArray *bodytext = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"td"];

for (HTMLNode *inputBody in bodytext) {
    //NSLog(@"%@", [inputBody getAttributeNamed:@"class"]);
    NSString *test = rawContentsOfNode(xmlNode *bodytext, htmlDocPtr doc);
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any example of using the updated version. and I can't figure out whats wrong. Any help with fixing this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the StackOverflow answer won't even compile because he has just copy-pasted the note in the original example.

This:

```
rawContentsOfNode(xmlNode *bodytext, htmlDocPtr doc);
```

is part of a function prototype not a function call.  It's a C function that requires and `xmlNode` and a `htmlDocPtr` as parameters.  Looking at [the interface of HTMLNode](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser/blob/master/HTMLNode.h), we see that the prototype given in the comment is wrong, it should be:

```
NSString* rawContentsOfNode(xmlNode *node);
```

There's no mention in the source code of a function matching the prototype recommended in the blog post.  I have no idea what they were talking about, unless it has been removed since the comment was made.

The XML node is a public member of the HTML node, so you could do:

```
test = rawContentsOfNode(inputBody->_node);
```

But the method `rawContents` does that anyway so you might as well use it.

```
test = [inputBody rawContents];
```

Note that (again checking the source code) there is an issue in that the content of the node is assumed to be encoded in UTF-8 this may be true, but the default encoding for HTTP is ISO-8859-1 so it may not.

Comment: That is awesome. thank you very much. damn i thought i tried that already -_-.