# How to Parse XML using libxml2 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, libxml2

This is my XML

```
<MyXML ID="tester" Server="example.com">
  <CONF>
    <MYAPP LOCN="/Application/data/" DATADIR="/tmp/data">
     ..
  </CONF>
</MyXML>
```

This is the Code i'm using

```
  NSString *xmlFilePath =@"/Applications/conf/MyConf.xml";
  NSLog(@"%@",xmlFilePath);
  NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
  NSString *xPathQuery =@"/MyXML";
  NSArray *xmlArray = PerformXMLXPathQuery(xmlData,xPathQuery);
```

It gives me the full XML as NSArray. How to traverse through this NSArray or, how to use XPath to get exactly the Nodes and attributes. 
I've used

```
  NSString *xPathQuery =@"/MyXML[@ID]";
```

but it doesn't returns the attribute ID, it just returns null.

I think it would be best to traverse through the NSArray, but how to do that(I'm a newbie to Objective C and when i looked for traversing through the NSArray returned by ,i've just got examples for HTML NSArray only)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple libxml2 HTML parsing example, using Objective-c, Xcode, and HTMLparser.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h)

Comment: @WrightCS Could you really check that it's really duplicate, that question was about HTML Parsing, i'm asking about XML Parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `libxml2` [wrapper](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/XPathQuery.zip) and using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa [article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

```
NSArray *PerformXMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
```

> For an entire XML document, contained in the NSData object "document",
>   this function executes the XPath query in the NSString "query" and
>   returns an NSArray of NSDictionary node objects for nodes that match
>   the query.
>
> The only difference between the two listed functions is that the the
>   first expects proper XML data and the second expects HTML data.