# Parsing from web

Tags: objective-c, parsing, web

Any body can help me,
I want to parse from a website, since I'm new in Objective C, I have no clue what should I do, is there any sample code that I can see to get some idea?

Comment: What you want to parse? Html/xml or binary data? Do you want to parse it on-fly from stream or you want to download it first?

Comment: I want to parse the links of videos and also parse the links of the news. then show the links of the videos in a table and show the links of the news in a different table.

Comment: in this case you'd better use ASIHTTPRequest library... (see bellow).

Comment: @Tutankhamen Thank you. Unfortunately my question down voted and it causes to limit my access to ask a question, can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: ASI is good but no longer supported. Try MBRequest! https://github.com/mobiata/MBRequest

Comment: I don't know why my question down voted! I cannot ask a question anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unspecific, because the method is up to which kind of data you want to parse.

If you just want to fill a string with the contents of your website you could use:

```
NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

if you want to parse a xml or json file there are classes like the NSXMLParser.

Comment: Never call that method from the main thread. It will block and likely kill your application.

Comment: The website that I want to parse has links of videos and links of news, I want to parse these links

Comment: As @logancautrell said you will need a second thread for this operation.    `[self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(readThread) withObject: [NSThread currentThread]];`  As the next step you might read this Post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h) for some information about html parsing in Xcode

Comment: GCD is better :) prefer that over perform selector. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @logancautrell thanks a lot. My question got down voted and it causes to limit my access to ask a question, can anybody help me?

Comment: @logancautrell Thank you, I got reputation again:)