# How to implement values and text from website to a tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, ios

sorry but I'm a newbie in ios programming. So my question is:

I've a website, and on this website there are some cells with information about the specific car. Now I'm going to put some of this informations, like the price, into a row of the tableview cell with a image. I use to display the image:

```
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"link of image"]]];
```

And I want to display the title from the car, which you can found on the website, on the tableview.

The website is: [here](http://home.mobile.de/MOLTER-UNFALLWAGEN#ses)

Does have anyone suggestions to do this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please don't call it Xcode programming (and remove the 'Xcode' tag too). It's iOS programming or Objective-C programming or programming using the Cocoa Touch API, but if you used `vi` and `make` to write iOS apps instead of Xcode, the question would not be different.

Comment: You can do this by using xml parsing or by using json parsing

Comment: do u own that site.? or u want to display that data from other's site..?

Comment: @vishy, actually it runs over a main server called "mobile.de", but I can have acces to the code! Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use html parsing and get data "[use this links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h)" ,[example](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)

Answer (score 0):

Then if you have the access to database, then you can write your own server side code to get the data from database using php generating xml or json data. Have this php code on the server, by using the link your app gets the data from the server in xml or json form.

Then parse these data and display in your app.

You can this tutorial by raywenderlich,

[How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)